Does Stefan's law give the intensity of all the electromagnetic radiation or just infrared radiation?

The Stefan–Boltzmann law, also known as Stefan's law, describes the intensity of the thermal radiation emitted by matter in terms of that matter's temperature. (WIKIPEDIA)


The Stefan-Boltzmann Law states that the total amount of energy per unit area emitted by an object is proportional to the 4th power of the temperature.(Penn State Uni)


The total energy emitted/radiated per unit surface area of a blackbody across all wavelengths per unit time is directly proportional to the fourth power of the black body’s thermodynamic temperature.(ByJus)

I am confused which is correct. Does the result of calculation from Stefan's law include all the radiation emitted by the blackbody, which could be visible light, UV or Infrared.
Or, Does it just give the amount of energy radiated as Infrared light (Thermal radiation)


I am confused which is correct.

All of them. Basically you found three ways to say the same thing.

Does the result of calculation from Stefan's law include all the radiation emitted by the blackbody,

Yes. We obtain Stefan's law by integrating the spectral energy density given by Planck's law over all frequencies, not only infrared.

Does it just give the amount of energy radiated as Infrared light (Thermal radiation)

Thermal radiation is any energy emitted by an object due to Thermal excitations of its particles, not only infrared light. It happens that for room temperature, for majority of objects, this radiated energy founds to be in greatest part in infrared region. But for any object in any temperature, the thermal radiation can cover the whole spectrum, as the Planck's law shows.
